# Android - Recyclerview fragment crashes on device, not on emulator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am using a Recyclerview to display to textfields and an image view.  It works perfectly on the emulator (Genymotion Google Nexus 4 running 5.1) but I sent the APK file to my friend on email, the app works perfectly everywhere but when he taps on the navigation drawer item that takes him to the recycler view fragment, the app crashes.  He has a Galaxy Note 5 running Android 6.

Here's the code for the people fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class People extends Fragment {
PeopleAdapter adapter;

public People() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Home.inHome = false;


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.peopleRecyclerView);

    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    PeopleAdapter adapter = new PeopleAdapter(this.getContext(),getData(), (MainActivity) this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    return view;


}

public static ArrayList<Person> getData(){
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    people = WelcomeScreen.downloadedPeople;
    return people;
}

public AssetManager getAsset(){
    return getActivity().getAssets();
}

}
```

And here's the adapter I am using for the recycler view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PeopleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PeopleAdapter.PeopleViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Person> mPeople;
private Context mContext;
MainActivity main;



public PeopleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Person> people, MainActivity ma){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
    mPeople = people;
    main = ma;
}





@Override
public PeopleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.peoplecell,parent,false);

    PeopleViewHolder viewHolder = new PeopleViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PeopleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindPerson(mPeople.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPeople.size();
}

public class PeopleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView name;
    TextView bio;
    ImageView image;
    String personImagePath;
    public Context myContext;
    public PeopleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        bio = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bioView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


    }
    public void bindPerson(Person person){
    name.setText(person.getName());
        bio.setText(person.getBio());
        for(int i=0;i<WelcomeScreen.peopleImagesFiles.size();i++){
            personImagePath =  WelcomeScreen.peopleImagesFiles.get(i).getName();
            if (personImagePath.substring(15,16).equals(person.getImage())){
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(WelcomeScreen.peopleImagesFiles.get(i).getAbsolutePath());

                image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
        int targetWidth = 100;
        int targetHeight = 100;
        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                        ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);
        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
                new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                        sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
                new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
        return targetBitmap;
    }
}
}
```

I am so confused to why this is working perfectly on simulator and not device. What do you think?

UPDATE: Here's the error I am getting:
                                                                    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 602997148 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 450MB until OOM
                                                                        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
                                                                        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4211)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4085)
                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3935)
                                                                        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                                                                        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:157)
                                                                        at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:145)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                        at com.anasghanim.gws.teamsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(teamsAdapter.java:49)
                                                                        at com.anasghanim.gws.teamsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(teamsAdapter.java:26)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5833)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5057)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4967)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2843)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20159)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20159)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20159)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:706)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
                                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:771)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20159)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1085)
                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20159)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.j

Comment: can you please share as the error log , that you are getting on emulator

Comment: WelcomeScreen.peopleImagesFiles.get(i).getAbsolutePath() are you loading any image from phone with this?

Comment: @HourGlass, well as I said, it works perfectly on the emulator no errors.  It crashes on the device, but I don't have an Android so I can't connect it to Studio.  I am going to see my friend and connect it now

Comment: @HourGlass, these are temp photos I downloaded from Firebase

Comment: so you downloaded and kept it in your phone , is that what you meant to say

Comment: Yes exactly right, @HourGlass

Comment: In Android Marshmallow , you have to  obtain runtime permission for reading data in  storage from user. I think that's causing you the issue. Check once and let me know.

Comment: Oh ok! That could be it! I am seeing my friend in 30 mins, I will let you know if that fixed it.  I will also connect his phone to my computer so I can read the error logs.  Thank you so much, @HourGlass!

Comment: Hi @HourGlass! Turns out that it's an out of memory error! Tried so many ways to load the images in a different way with no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use Glide or Picasso to load bitmap from your uri. the file you have downloaded was too big , usually bitmap size is reduced to <4 mb in android so, this is your best idea.

Comment: I tried Picasso like this:                     Picasso.with(mContext).load(WelcomeScreen.peopleImagesFiles.get(i)).resize(100,100).into(image); in the bindPeople method and still getting the same error :( Anything else I can try, @HourGlass?

Comment: what's the width and height of your downloaded file. and it's size.

Comment: They are 9 images all less than 50 KB and they are 100*100

Comment: Here's the error I am getting:

Comment: try this, after setting bitmap here ,image.setImage(myBitmap); myBitmap.recycle(); // this will release the memory allocated for the bitmap . you won't get out of memory error.

Comment: That didn't fix it, @HourGlass :( I added the error to the post, see if you can pick up something out of it.